# Access/SQL - My LIKE sentence is not working, and I desperately need to know why

Tags: sql, ms-access-2010

```
SELECT cod
     , item
     , sn
     , num
FROM Product p
INNER JOIN Zol z
   ON p.[num] = z.[item]
where p.num like "50-%"
```

Of course it was for testing purposes, so the only answer should be "50-56", but it's not returning me any results :/

Answer (score 4):

The wildcard for MS Access in a `LIKE` is the non-standard `*`.  So, try this:

```
SELECT cod, item, sn, num
FROM Product p INNER JOIN
     Zol z
     ON p.[num] = z.[item] 
WHERE p.num like "50-*"
```